# Immediately browned leaves on coral bark maple

Tags: leaves, diseases, maple, discoloration

Four months ago I transplanted two young maple trees, a coral bark and a Japanese, from nursery pots to larger pots. I went on vacation and the automatic irrigation did not trigger. Both scorched, which is something I’m unfortunately familiar with. The coral bark has continued to sprout bright green, healthy looking leaves but they immediately die, turning brown and curled within two days.

Deep watering twice a week, indirect sunlight for six hours per day. It has been three months of immediately dying leaves. The existing leaves have not died.

Any ideas how to save this? What could it be if not scorch, which I’ve never seen only affect new leaves?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]